# Does Huffman algorithm generate a minimal weight of a tree?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, huffman-coding

Does [Huffman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) generate a minimal weight of a tree?

I noticed that by trying to make two different trees with the same frequencies of letters, I get different weights of the trees.

We defined the weight of the tree as $\displaystyle\sum_{c\in C}f(c)d(c)$ where $C$ is all the letters, $f()$ is the frequency of the letter, $d()$ is the depth in the tree of that letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you normalize the frequencies so that they add to 1, then the weight of the tree is just the average codeword length, which is exactly what Huffman's algorithm tries to minimize. Check [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Formalized_description) of the Wikipedia article you link to.

Comment: I saw that on the wiki page, I'm not sure I understood it though. So If the weight of the tree corresponds to an average word length, then a small difference in the weight of the tree between two Huffman codes over the same input is expected?

Comment: No, any two Huffman codes should have exactly the same weight. Every Huffman code (that is, every code produced by Huffman's algorithm) provably has minimal weight.